# When is a lock acquired during a trigger's execution?

Tags: postgresql, trigger, locking

## Following Situation

I'm trying to determine when a lock is acquired during the execution/firing of a trigger. I have the following setup.

#### Table Definition

```
CREATE TABLE a(
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  data boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE
 );
```

#### Function

```
CREATE FUNCTION trig_func_before_update_a() RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
  RAISE NOTICE 't2 starts here';
  RETURN NEW;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

#### Trigger Definition

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig_test BEFORE UPDATE ON a
  FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE trig_func_before_update_a();
```

## Testing

Suppose we have two concurrent transactions

#### Transaction t1

```
UPDATE a SET data=data IS NOT data WHERE id=1;
```

The transaction t1 reaches the `RAISE NOTICE` inside the trigger and then the transaction t2 is concurrently started:

#### Transaction t2

```
PERFORM FROM a WHERE id=1 FOR UPDATE;
```

#### Locking Behaviour

After some tests, the row seems locked before the trigger is executed.
I found nothing in documentation speaking about that.

## Question

Is there any information about this behaviour or are there certain caveats I am hitting?

## Solution

Following @a_horse_with_no_name's comment

> "A trigger doesn't acquire a lock on its own. The DML statement firing
> the trigger will acquire a lock."

Comment: A trigger doesn't acquire a lock on its own. The DML statement _firing_ the trigger will acquire a lock.

Comment: I've tried to make the question more understandable and hope you can help me with the **Transaction t2** part. I wasn't able to determine what you are doing in that step. Anyway, I've voted to re-open the question after editing it.